# Como apagar conteúdo de arquivo TXT usando PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3

Estou fazendo um projeto web em php para monitorar com ping os ativos de rede no meu trabalho
Tenho um arquivo de nome 'log.txt' na raiz do meu projeto que é alimentado com informações de log com data, hora, ip etc. Linha por linha. Segue exemplo:

```
function functionLog($vSetor, $vIp, $vTaxa, $vPorta) {
    $fp = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    $dataLog = date("d/m/Y");
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Belem');
    $horaLog = date("H:i:s");
    fwrite($fp, $dataLog . ' ' . $horaLog . ' ' . $vSetor . ' ' . $vIp . ' ' . $vTaxa . 'ms' . ' ' . $vPorta . "\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Mas chega um momento em que este arquivo está muito cheio de informações de log e preciso esvaziar com apenas um clique

Minha duvida é: como posso chamar uma função dentro de um botão html para que o arquivo seja zerado, isto é, que seja apagada todas as linhas do arquivo 'log.txt'

Comment: Se você abrir o arquivo no modo `w`, todo o conteúdo do arquivo será sobrescrito, então não é melhor dentro da função `functionLog` você verificar o tamanho do arquivo e se for maior que o limite desejado ele abrir o arquivo como `w`?

Comment: A quantidade de linhas é ilimitada. Não importa quantas linhas apareça no log
E esta função foi o exemplo que usei para mostrar como o arquivo txt é criado
Minha dúvida agora é sobre como apagar as linhas desse arquivo txt

Comment: Pode chamar uma página via *ajax*. Nessa página você deleta o arquivo e cria um em branco pra receber as novas informações... Se interessar, posso formular uma resposta.

Comment: O que eu queria aprender era isso aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button
Agora já sei como fazer
RESOLVIDO

Answer (score 0):

Você tem uma outra alternativa.

Poderia invocar a função utilizando o botão de um formulário.

E para ele ter uma aparência legal, poderia estilizar com css.

Por exemplo:

Formulário HTML

```
<form action="/urlaqui" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="botao">Invocar Função</button>
</form>
```

Invocar função PHP após clique no botão

```
<?php
    // Verifica se o botão foi clicado
    if( isset($_POST['botao']) ){
       // Se o botão existe, executa a função
       executeEstaFuncao();
    }
```

Estilizando botão com CSS

```
form button{
    background-color:#ccc;
    border:1px solid #444;
    color:#666;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:1.1em;
}
```